# Как заменить title на конкретной странице в WordPress, плагин All in One SEO Pack (AIOSP)

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть файл d-seo.php 
Содержимое такое:

```
<?
        //Глобальные значения (по умолчанию)
        $aSEOData_title="";
        $aSEOData['title'] = '';
        $aSEOData['descr'] = '';
        $aSEOData['keywr'] = '';
        $aSEOData['h1'] = '';
        $aSEOData['text_under'] = '';

        //Определяем адрес (REQUEST_URI есть не всегда)
        $sSEOUrl =  html_entity_decode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        //Собственно вариации для страниц
        switch ($sSEOUrl) {
            case '/kursi-barbera/.../':
            $aSEOData['title'] = 'Нужный title';
            $aSEOData['descr'] = 'Нужный description';
            $aSEOData['keywr'] = '';
            $aSEOData['h1'] = '';
            $aSEOData['text_over'] = '';
            $aSEOData['text_under'] = '';
            break;   
        }
        function changeHeadBlock ($sContent, $sRegExp, $sBlock) {
            if (preg_match($sRegExp, $sContent)) {
                return preg_replace($sRegExp, $sBlock, $sContent);
            }
            else {
                return str_replace('<head>', '<head>' . $sBlock, $sContent);
            }
        }
        if (isset($aSEOData['title']) && !empty($aSEOData['title'])) {
            $aSEOData_title=$aSEOData['title'];
            $aSEOData['title'] = htmlspecialchars($aSEOData['title']);
            //$sContent = changeHeadBlock($sContent, '#<title>.*</title>#siU', '<title>' . $aSEOData['title'] . '</title>');
            $sContent = changeHeadBlock($sContent, '#<meta property="og:title.*>#siU', '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$aSEOData['title'].'" />');
        }
        if (isset($aSEOData['descr']) && !empty($aSEOData['descr'])) {
            $aSEOData['descr'] = htmlspecialchars($aSEOData['descr']);
            $sContent = changeHeadBlock($sContent, '#<meta[^>]+name[^>]{1,7}description[^>]*>#siU', '<meta name="description" content="' . $aSEOData['descr'] . '" />');
            $sContent = changeHeadBlock($sContent, '#<meta property="og:description.*>#siU', '<meta property="og:description" content="'.$aSEOData['descr'].'" />');
        }
        if (isset($aSEOData['keywr']) && !empty($aSEOData['keywr'])) {
            $aSEOData['keywr'] = htmlspecialchars($aSEOData['keywr']);
            $sContent = changeHeadBlock($sContent, '#<meta[^>]+name[^>]{1,7}keywords[^>]*>#siU', '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $aSEOData['keywr'] . '" />');
        }
        if (isset($aSEOData['h1']) && !empty($aSEOData['h1'])) {
            $sContent = preg_replace('#<h1(.*)>.*</h1>#siU', '<h1$1>'.$aSEOData['h1'].'</h1>', $sContent);
        }

        if (isset($aSEOData['text_over']) && !empty($aSEOData['text_over'])) {
            $sContent = str_replace('<!--text_over-->', "<section class='default-seo'>" . $aSEOData['text_over'] . "</section>", $sContent);
        }
        if (isset($aSEOData['text_under']) && !empty($aSEOData['text_under'])) {
            $sContent = str_replace('<!--text_under-->', "<section class='default-seo'>" . $aSEOData['text_under'] . "</section>", $sContent);
        }
        ?>
```

Используется плагин All in One SEO Pack, пытаюсь заменить содержимое `<title></title>`

Написал такой код в functions.php

```
function buffer_end1() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end1');
function callback($buffer) {
    $sContent = $buffer;
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/d-seo.php';
    if(!empty($aSEOData_title)){
        add_filter( 'aioseop_title', 'change_wordpress_seo_title' );
        function change_wordpress_seo_title( $title ){
            return $aSEOData_title;
        }
    }
    return $sContent;
}



ob_start("callback"); // прописал в header.php
```

og:title заменяется корректно, и значение там верное, а значение в `<title></title>` некорректное, почему используя функцию callback, не получается заменить вывод title? Почему в title прописывается значение, которое взято из h1 страницы, а не то которое передано ( $aSEOData_title )?

[WordPress filter to modify final html output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772510/wordpress-filter-to-modify-final-html-output), отталкивался от этого вопроса, но тут немного не то. Заменить может быть и получается, но если правильно понял, плагин заменяет значение.

Сразу извиняюсь, если как-то криво объяснил.

Comment: Это делается непосредственно в админке - в редакторе поста, а не извращаются с кодом. https://i.imgur.com/Afhx2XR.jpg

Comment: Цель другая, нужно сделать именно то что написано, по какой причине так не работает. То что вы показали, не подходит . Разные страницы могут иметь разный принцип составления title и тд .

Comment: Тогда тебе не нужен плагин. А за `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/d-seo.php'` я бы вообще руки открывал.

Comment: Цель изменить то что сделал плагин. Плагин все еще нужен, но там не очень гибкая настройка.Нужно менять title который генерит плагин.
`include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/d-seo.php'` Почему так нельзя?

Comment: В плагине - нормальные настройки.

Answer (score 0):

В общем долго разбираясь, смог это реализовать, изменил функцию в functions.php

```
function buffer_end1() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end1');

function callback($buffer) {
  // modify buffer here, and then return the updated code
    $sContent = $buffer;
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/d-seo.php';
    $aSEOData_title=$aSEOData['title'];
    if(!empty($aSEOData['title'])){
        add_filter( 'aioseop_title', function ( $title ) use ($aSEOData){
            return $aSEOData['title'];
        });
    }
    return $sContent;
}
```